# How to allow an svg to be clickable within a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have the following html:

```
<a class="delete show-modal" href="#;">
    <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="12px" height="12px" viewBox="0 0 10 10" focusable="false"><polygon class="a-s-fa-Ha-pa" fill="#969696" points="10,1.01 8.99,0 5,3.99 1.01,0 0,1.01 3.99,5 0,8.99 1.01,10 5,6.01 8.99,10 10,8.99 6.01,5 "></polygon></svg>
</a>
```

Currently, I'm unable to click the link to trigger a popup display. Is there a way to make the svg part of the "link text" without using javascript (for example, just using css or changing the html), or what can I do here?

Additionally, here is how I'm triggering the popup:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {

    var clickedElement = $(e.target);
    $this = clickedElement;
    if ($this.hasClass('show-modal')) {

        ...
    }

});
```

In other words, I believe the popup is not being triggered, because the clicked element shows up as `svg` and not as `a`.

Comment: The error is not in this code, it is in the question you've asked. Your SVG _is_ part of the link, and will fire events attached to the link, given this code. If you are asking how to code a popup, that is a different issue.

Comment: @Ted thanks, you're right. I've updated the questing with a bit more detail. It has to do with what `e.target` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the svg is the clicked target, and it does not have the class you are looking for. To fix this, you can either add the `show-modal` class to all the elements within the anchor, or simply add this CSS:

```
.show-modal *{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The `pointer-events` CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events. Here is more information on [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

See this snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var clickedElement = $(e.target);
  $this = clickedElement;
  if ($this.hasClass('show-modal')) {
    alert('it got clicked');
  }
});
```

```css
.show-modal * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="delete show-modal" href="#;">
  <svg x="0px" y="0px" width="12px" height="12px" viewBox="0 0 10 10" focusable="false"><polygon class="a-s-fa-Ha-pa" fill="#969696" points="10,1.01 8.99,0 5,3.99 1.01,0 0,1.01 3.99,5 0,8.99 1.01,10 5,6.01 8.99,10 10,8.99 6.01,5 "></polygon></svg>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks, this is a great answer. What does the `pointer-events` css do? I've never seen that item before. I'll look it up, but it would be great if you could just add a line or two in your answer about that

Comment: @David542 it essentially tells the browser to ignore the mouse--as if the element isn't even there.---Ah I see you added in a description and link. Excellent :)

Answer (score 0):

Your svg it's already a part of your link. Maybe your question is "how can I show a popup without using javascript ?"
In this case you can use the css property :target

https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO

```
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```